# url Slug php and htaccess issue

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to create a slug to jump from home page to article page with the title as a slug.

here are my .htaccess codes:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^post/([a-zA-Z0-9_]-)/([0-9]+)\$ article.php?id_art=$1 [NC,L]
```

and here is my php link:

```
<a href='article/post/$id_art/$slug'><button class='read-more-btn'>Read more</button></a>
```

The slug in url appears pefectly like this:

http://localhost/sitename/article/post/8/the-slug-i-want-to-appear

but I got this result:

**Object not found!**

**Error 404**

what's the problem guys ? I guess it's the .htaccess. help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your regex backwards. You have `post` then `ID` then `slug`, but your regex matches `post` then `slug` (numbers/letters/underscores) then `ID`. Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ article.php?id_art=$1 [NC,L]
```

Note that you should have been getting an error for the expression: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]-`, which isn't valid.

Comment: I got the same problem :'(

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you have a rule that matches `^post/`( but you don't have a rule for article, try `RewriteRule ^article/post/([a-zA-Z0-9_]-)/([0-9]+)\$ article.php?id_art=$1` [NC,L]` and see if that helps.

You also have `sitename` which isn't in the rule. What is your original url you're trying to rewrite with the article.php in the link? Try to include that also.

Comment: I tryied `RewriteRule ^article/post/([a-zA-Z0-9_]-)/([0-9]+)\$ article.php?id_art=$1 [NC,L]` and same result, but the site name can't be in .htaccess

I have article.php inside article folder on localhost

http://localhost/StarDevelop/article/post/8/the-title-slug